# Android SQlite database syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

Given the following code-

```
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //creating table_to
    String CREATE_TABLE_TO = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TO
            + "("
            + TABLE_TO_PACKAGE_ID + " INTEGER, "
            + TABLE_TO_PACKAGE_TO + " TEXT, "
            + " PRIMARY KEY " + " ( " + TABLE_TO_PACKAGE_ID + "," + TABLE_TO_PACKAGE_TO + " ) "
            + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TO);
```

The following error generate-

```
5860-5860/com.example.social.gps I/SqliteDatabaseCpp﹕ sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "to": syntax error, db=xxx

5860-5860/com.example.social.gps W/System.err﹕ android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "to": syntax error: , while compiling: CREATE TABLE to(pack_id INTEGER, pack_to TEXT,  PRIMARY KEY  ( pack_id,pack_to ) )
```

The same happens with every LEGAL sql command, I have tested all of them in two SQL servers, all worked. I took the exact sentences from the log and pasted in there and they are legal.

For instance -

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //creating table_to
    String CREATE_TABLE_TO = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TO
            + "("
            + TABLE_TO_PACKAGE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , "
            + TABLE_TO_PACKAGE_TO + " TEXT "
            + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TO);
```

yeild-

```
 17855-17855/com.example.social.gps I/SqliteDatabaseCpp﹕ sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "to": syntax error, db=xxx

 17855-17855/com.example.social.gps W/System.err﹕ android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "to": syntax error: , while compiling: CREATE TABLE to(pack_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , pack_to TEXT )
```

I have tried with all sorts of spaces between the `,` and `(` `)` characters, non worked.
I have also tried to change the database name.

***SOLVED. Answer Posted.***

Comment: what is the value of `TABLE_TO_PACKAGE_TO` and `TABLE_TO`?

Comment: Add: AUTOINCREMENT to your primary key too.

Comment: Jonas452 - I dont want it to be quto incremented.

Comment: shayan pourvatan - you can see at the log messages.

Comment: What do you see for CREATE_TABLE_TO when you print it to the console just prior to the db.execSQL ?

Comment: i dont print it. you can see it at the log error. you want me to print the string?

Comment: What has the MySQL documentation to do with this? You should have looked at the [SQLite documentaion](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

Comment: @user2162550 If the problem is solved, you should post an answer of your own below and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***SOLVED.***

**ANSWER:** changing `"to"` table name to `"to_"` solved it. (The same for a table I named `"for"`, changed it to `"for_"` and it worked). According to SQLite documentation, `"TO"` and `"FOR"` are saved words, and apparently the SQLite is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot the semicolon at the end of the create statement. Like this:

```
+ ");";
```